# Assembly version mismatch with system.web.mvc, syncFusion

Tags: assemblies, version, syncfusion

I am trying to execute a sample provided by Syncfusion and I get an assembly error.

```
(0): error CS1705: Assembly 'Syncfusion.Schedule.Mvc, Version=10.104.0.44, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I thought I just had to remove the failing reference and add my higher version, number 4. Unfortunatly, on the build, the project keeps on trying to build with the version 2.

I should at least have this:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

But on the build I get this:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the project you are building is an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and not an ASP.NET MVC 2 project.  Given this error, it looks like you are using SyncFusion components that are designed for MVC 3 only.

Comment: It is indeed a problem in the project setup, the one available for download. They forgot to add the batch file able to convert from Mvc2ToMvc3 and vice versa. Thanks!

Comment: Great glad I could help. (if you don't mid marking this as te answer that would be good as well)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below,

1. If you are using Syncfusion samples, then we would suggest you to check the Configuration Manager. If you are using MVC-2 then please set Configuration Manager as debug and if you are using MVC-3 then please set Configuration Manager as debug-MVC3.

   Note: Configuration Manager will be available in Build Menu
2. If you have created your own sample we would suggest you to check the dll reference in the project and run the MVC switcher and assembly manager. Please refer the below link.

http://help.syncfusion.com/resources/Content/ug_101/user%20interface/asp.net%20mvc/grid/documents/612howtoswitchbetwee.htm

Regards,

Sridhar N